Dynamic GitlabCI repo selection
I've been trying to configure gitlab-ci.yml so as to get a specific branch, dependent on the commit-branch naming convention.
We have a project group named "cfe" and both project-to-commit & gitlab-ci repo are under it.
Configured gitlabci UI to get gitlab-ci.yml from the latter.
What i want to do it fall to a specific branch of gitlab-repo, according to original branch naming. So far, i reached this point (gitlab-ci.yml):
  - project: 'cfe/gitlab-ci-repo'
    file: '.gitlab-ci.yml'
    ref: "branch_A"
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^name_convention_A.*$/'
        when: always

  - project: 'cfe/gitlab-ci-repo'
    file: '.gitlab-ci.yml'
    ref: "branch_B"
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^name_convention_B.*$/'
        when: always

  - project: 'cfe/gitlab-ci-repo'
    file: '.gitlab-ci.yml'
    ref: "fallback_to_default"
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ /^name_convention_A.*$/ && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ /^name_convention_B.*$/' #when pattern does not match the preceding rules
        when: always

This is working ok, when using explicit exclusions.
The problem is that i have over 10 naming conventions and the last regexp will be too long, therefore i need a generic pattern or just a rule which will just fallback to the default branch, if none of the rules above are valid. I used several methods but no luck so far. Any ideas?
Thank you!
